# React - Route will not render new contents

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-link

I have different URLS that are not rendering results.

The behavior is:

1)I have a dynamic list of links, one link for each item created in the database which has a unique ID. When I click on one of these links for the first time, and am coming from a different website page, the web page works as expected and I view the correct item.

So I come from: http://localhost:8000/#/people

And then I go to: http://localhost:8000/#/contract/view/7cf403ff-820a-449e-81cc-ed4241a44c6a

This is ok, and this works as expected.

2)I now click on another item to view its details.  The URL is similar, but has a different ID.

New URL:  http://localhost:8000/#/contract/view/188bcabc-7a6e-432e-a638-4446884e5086

When I click on this link the page does NOT re-render the new contents. However, I can see the new URL in the browser.  Also, if I refresh the browser with this new URL I will then see the new contents.  It's as though React thinks this new link is the same as the last.

I am using the 'Link' tag.  I've been trying to find a solution for many hours or even simply information on why this would happen.  All other pages render fine, it's just when I click on these particular set of links directly after the other with no page hits in between.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are on the same path then component is already rendered in the page, so componentDidMount will not execute, in your component add componentDidUpdate which will run whenever route changes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you fetching some value depending on the new ID from `useEffect()` hook?

Otherwise the page/component is same for all IDs. You need to fetch the data in `useEffect()` and update the state using `setState()`. Only by updating a state, your component will re-render.

Please provide some example of your code to make the issue clear to understand.